# How to resize a WPF element on a static event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, layout

I have a GUI with elements that should be displayed with a specific size in millimeters.
For this purpose I have a (global) static class `PPMM` (= pixels per millimeter) with a `double? Factor` and an `event FactorChanged`, both static. The setter of `Factor` calls the `FactorChanged` event handler.
The elements in the GUI are UserControls and hook (in constructor) to the `FactorChanged` event to update their pixel sizes or ScaleTransforms.

When layouting the GUI, I don't want to create UserControls for every object to be sized in millimeters.
Rather, I'd like to use something in the way of

```
<elem Margin="0, {?:getPixelsFromMillimeters(
    desiredSize:{x:Const 20mm},
    fallback:{x:Const 80px})}" />
```

The *mm size* and the fallback *pixel size* should be bindable.

I thought about binding to `Factor` and using an `IValueConverter` with the desired *mm size* in the `parameter` of the converter. But then I can't bind to a variable *mm size* value.

I could bind to the *mm size* and use a converter, but then changing `Factor` wouldn't update the measure.

I also didn't manage to create a DependencyProperty in a static class (`GetValue` and `SetValue` are not available there), but that would be a different SO question...

**What are proper ways to achieve what I'm trying to do?**

Are there details I left unanswered? If yes, please leave a comment.

Comment: why "`changing Factor wouldn't update the measure`"? If your binding will updates when property changed ("`The setter of Factor calls the FactorChanged event handler.`"), it have to be changed. I think that converter + binding can solve your problem right way.

Comment: @stukselbax I tried that via a dependencyproperty, but that seemingly doesn't work in a static class. Current implementation: Factor = common static property, FactorChanged = custom static event handler

Comment: Does `static` is so important in your case? Think about it...

Comment: @stukselbax It must be some kind of singleton, because the elements must be able to address it globally.

Comment: So I have no question anymore)  any ideas which comes in my mind are stupid...

Comment: @stukselbax But thanks anyways ^^ - Right now I'm trying to implement a different singleton approach - after lunch. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a working answer myself from stukselbax' comments...

*In short:* Some WPF size or other measure property multibinds to the static DependencyProperty *Factor* and to some static doubles as parameters (size in mm, fallback size in pixels) via an IMultiValueConverter. The static *Factor* comes from a singleton. There is an additional event *FactorChanged* in the singleton that other classes can subscribe.

Create a class to use as singleton instance:

```
public class PPMMSingleton : DependencyObject
{
    public double? Factor
    {
        get { return (double?)GetValue(FactorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FactorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Factor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Factor", typeof(double?), typeof(PPMMSingleton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFactorChanged),
                new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceFactor)));

    private static object CoerceFactor(DependencyObject element, object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public static void OnFactorChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        PPMMSingleton ppmm = (PPMMSingleton)sender;

        ppmmEventArgs e =
            new ppmmEventArgs(
                (double?)args.OldValue,
                (double?)args.NewValue);
        ppmm.OnFactorChanged(e);
    }

    private void OnFactorChanged(ppmmEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FactorChanged != null)
            FactorChanged(e);
    }

    public event ppmmEventHandler FactorChanged;
}
```

Create delegate and EventArgs for FactorChanged:

```
public delegate void ppmmEventHandler(ppmmEventArgs e);

public class ppmmEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ppmmEventArgs(double? oldFactor, double? newFactor)
    {
        OldFactor = oldFactor;
        NewFactor = newFactor;
    }

    public double? OldFactor { get; private set; }
    public double? NewFactor { get; private set; }
}
```

Create a static class to host this singleton:

```
public static class PPMM
{
    public static double? Factor
    {
        get { return Singleton.Factor; }
        set
        {
            Singleton.Factor = value;
        }
    }

    private static PPMMSingleton _singleton = null;
    public static PPMMSingleton Singleton
    {
        get
        {
            if (_singleton == null)
                _singleton = new PPMMSingleton();
            return _singleton;
        }
    }

    public static event ppmmEventHandler FactorChanged
    {
        add { Singleton.FactorChanged += value; }
        remove { Singleton.FactorChanged -= value; }
    }
}
```

Create an IMultiValueConverter that takes the Factor, the size in mm and an optional size in pixels as fallback:

```
public class FactorAndMillimeterToPixelConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Member

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((values.Length < 2)
            || !(values[0] is double?))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        double? factor = (double?)values[0];

        switch(values.Length)
        {
            case 2:
                if(!(values[1] is double))
                    return Binding.DoNothing;
                // values[0]: Factor, values[1]: SizeMM
                // if Factor is null, no fallback provided -> donothing
                if (!factor.HasValue)
                    return Binding.DoNothing;
                // else return calculated width
                return factor.Value * (double)values[1];

            case 3:
                if (!(values[1] is double) || !(values[2] is double))
                    return Binding.DoNothing;
                // values[0]: Factor, values[1]: SizeMM, values[2]: SizePixelsFallback
                // if Factor is null, but fallback provided -> return fallback
                if (!factor.HasValue)
                    return (double)values[2];
                // else return calculated width
                return factor.Value * (double)values[1];

            default:
                // value.Length > 3
                return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Put a resource with the converter in your XAML:

```
        <mynamespace:FactorAndMillimeterToPixelConverter x:Key="fm2pconv" />
```

MultiBind to the static Factor dependency property and to the size in mm and the fallback size in pixels (both as static doubles) in the XAML:

```
    <Border>
        <Border.Width>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource fm2pconv}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding Path="Factor" Source="{x:Static tc:PPMM.Singleton}" />
                    <Binding>
                        <Binding.Source>
                            <sys:Double>50</sys:Double>
                        </Binding.Source>
                    </Binding>
                    <Binding>
                        <Binding.Source>
                            <sys:Double>400</sys:Double>
                        </Binding.Source>
                    </Binding>
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Border.Width>
        <TextBlock
            Text="Wenn Factor gesetzt ist, ist dieser Kasten 50mm breit. Ansonsten ist er 400px breit. Seine Width wird beeinflusst."
            TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
            >
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
```

One could also bind the size in mm to a dependency property (assuming the correct DataContext is set):

```
        <Border.Width>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource fm2pconv}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding Path="Factor" Source="{x:Static tc:PPMM.Singleton}" />
                    <Binding Path="WidthInMMInCodeBehind" />
                    <Binding Path="FallbackWidthInPixelsInCodeBehind" />
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Border.Width>
```

Voilà!